# Read live video stream from port and play in form C#

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-streaming, video-capture

I need to find code that will allow me to be able to connect a freeview box to my laptop, read the incoming LIVE video stream and play it in a form. I then would like to overlay an image on top of this stream advertising pub offers. Is this a project for C# or is there software out there that can allow this manipulation of the live video? I will then be connecting the laptop back to a tv via the HDMI output.

Any help or direction would be great

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try and get Microsoft Expression Encoder 4. It comes with the Encoder SDK which includes classes that developers can use to stream and manipulate video. It also comes with sample code to help you do that.

I hope this helps.